# list(set()) doesn't give me the list order I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I have a `list of dicts` like this:

```py
a = [{'key1':val, 'key2':val, 'key3':val},{'key1':val, 'key2':val, 'key3':val}]
```

And I'm trying to get a keys from values to one list like this:

```
a = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

With this code

```py
key_list = set().union(*(b.keys() for b in a))
key_list = list(key_list)

>>> ['key2', 'key1', 'key3']
```

Which works, but the order of values is not same, is it because I'm inserting the data to `set`? How could I make it with the same values(keys) order?

Comment: If the keys are string, you can sort them yourself by `key_list = sorted( list(key_list) )`

Comment: Do you want keys that show up in multiple dicts shown once, or a list for keys in every dict?

Comment: only once please

Comment: what defines order to you? alphabetical order of key names, or order of keynames that you've listed them in the constructor for `a`?

Comment: order of keynames in `a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Core issue**

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) don't remember insertion order.  They tend to scramble the data according to the underlying *hash()* function.

To remember order, consider using a list or [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

**Solution using a list backed by a set**

```
>>> a = [{'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3},{'key1':4, 'key2':5, 'key3':6}]
>>> key_list = []
>>> seen = set()
>>> for d in a:
        for k in d:
            if k not in seen:
                seen.add(k)
                key_list.append(k)

>>> key_list
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

This uses a list called *key_list* to remember order and uses a set called *seen* to track whether keys have already been seen.

**Solution using an OrderedDict**

This approach is shorter but a little fancy:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(a)))
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

This uses [*chain.from_iterable()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to flatten the input into a single string of keys.  Then, [*OrderedDict.fromkeys()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) combines them into a dictionary while remembering order and eliminating duplicates.  Lastly, [*list()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) turns the result into the desired list.

Answer (score 1):

Just build the list yourself. E.g.

```
lst = []

# Loop through all dictionaries
for dct in a:

    # Loop through all keys of the current dictionary
    for key in dct.keys():

        # If the key is already in the list, skip it
        if key in lst:
            continue

        # Append the key to the list
        lst.append(key)

print(lst) # ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

Comment: Using only lists can be inperformant. This can take a long time on huge dicts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent, you want an ordered list of unique keys for your dictionaries. Your current approach presents one problem: the values returned from a set are not necessarily in the same order they were added in. I'd say your approach is almost there. All you need to do now is sort the list, which will guarantee order.

```
key_list = set().union(*(b.keys() for b in a))
key_list = sorted(list(key_list))

>>> ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

**Update:**
Since, it appears that you want them to appear as they are ordered in `a`, we have a little more work to do:

```
reference = set(a[0].keys())
key_list = list(a[0].keys())
for d in a[1:]:
    newkeys := [k in d.keys() if check_n_add(k, reference)]
    key_list.extend(newkeys)

func check_n_add(s, k):
    if k not in s:
        s.add(k)
        return True
    return False
```

That should preserve order even if the keys are not already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A set object is an unordered collection of hashable object. It does not maintain the order of data given. A possible answer could be of done using list comprehension.

```
d = []
[ d.append(c) for b in a for c in b.keys() if c not in d]
>>> d
# ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```